# Passing button name from name to function - Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm looking for help. 
I'm newbie in Django, python.

I'm want to pass name of clicked button to function in views and then use it as a filter.

This is html:

```
<tr>
  <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'display_ph' %}" role="button" method="post">{{ item.nazwa }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ item.ulica }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.miejscowosc }}</td>
  <td>{{ item.kod_pocztowy }}</td>
</tbody>
```

And I want to take "nazwa" and pass it to function:

```
def display_ph(request, nazwa):
  filter = request.GET.get('nazwa', False)
  items = Phandlowy.objects.filter(firma=filter)
  context = {
      'items': items,
  }
  return render(request, 'ph.html', context)
```

I don't now if it is possible with this button. 
Thank you for looking at this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it as query parameter:

```
<a href="{% url 'display_ph'  %}?nazwa={{item.nazwa}}">
```

And inside your view:

```
def display_ph(request):
    filter = request.GET.get('nazwa', False)
    items = Phandlowy.objects.filter(firma=filter)
    context = {
      'items': items,
    }
    return render(request, 'ph.html', context)
```